# Spring Data ManyToMany select query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities: User and Event. Each mapped to appropriate table. Also I have third table `user_event` because this two entities has relation many-to-many. And I need to select from DB all events where user participate in.

Event:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_event",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Collection<User> participants;
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String nickname;
```

`user_event` table do not has entity in java code. I tried this query:

```
@Query("select e from Event e join user_event ue on ue.event_id = e.id where ue.user_id = :userId and e.startDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
Page<Event> findAllForUser(Pageable pageable, @Param("userId") Long userId);
```

But this query cause exception on application start:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select e from Event e join user_event ue on ue.event_id = e.id where ue.user_id = :userId and e.startDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]
```

In MySQL Workbench I tries this:

```
select * from event e join user_event ue on e.id = ue.event_id where ue.user_id = 1 and e.startDate > now();
```

And it works. But how to create good working query for spring data?

SQL dump:

```
select count(event0_.id) as col_0_0_ from event event0_ inner join   address address1_ on event0_.address_id=address1_.id 
cross join user_event participan2_, user user3_ where   event0_.id=participan2_.event_id and participan2_.user_id=user3_.id 
and (? in (.)) and event0_.startDate>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: You're not taking advantage of JPA's mappings. I'm pretty sure Spring Data can express your query in just a plain repository name, but even in JPQL you should just need `select e from Event E where :user in event.participants` (and pass the `User` object instead of the ID).

Comment: @chrylis , it does not work - select e from Event E where :user in (event.participants)

Comment: Typo(s). Try `select e from Event e where :user in e.participants`.

Comment: @chrylis , the same error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))

Comment: Can you set your JPA provider to dump the SQL it's generating and post the stack trace? This looks like something's malfunctioning there.

Comment: @chrylis added to question

Comment: Huh? Where's the `address` coming from? It looks like you have relevant fields and/or query parameters you haven't posted.

Comment: @chrylis I just added it to check but even without address same exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In your @ManyToMany mapping you have the following:

> @JoinTable(name = "event_user_event"

but in the query you are using `user_event`. I guess one of them is typo?

2. In your query

   ```
   select e 
   from Event e join user_event ue on ue.event_id = e.id 
   where ue.user_id = :userId and e.startDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
   ```

you are using `user_event` which is not an entity (as it is correctly pointed in the exception message). So the query should look like the following :

```
select e 
from Event e join e.participants u 
where u.id = :userId and e.startDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Assuming your `User` entity has an attribute named `id`. And this query should return all events that are associated with the user `:userId`.